# how to change x axis labels so that its shown in 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 format etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to change the way the x labels on the x axis are represented in ggplot2 histogram, so that instead of being 0, 10, 20, 30, its shown 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40 etc.

I know this can be done manually but I was wondering if there was a more simple method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data like this :

```
set.seed(123)
vec <- sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(vec)
```

And you already have the `group` column, you can create `labels` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(group = ceiling(vec/10) * 10, 
         labels = paste(group-10, group, sep = '-')) -> df1
```

and use `scale_x_continuous` in `geom_histogram` :

```
ggplot(df1) + aes(group) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df1$group), labels = unique(df1$labels))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however is there a way of doing this directly in ggplot2 rather than mutating?

Comment: @newbie Sure it is possible but for it you should provide your data in a reproducible format that we can copy-paste. You have provided no information in your question about how your data looks like. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).